# Cassandra or mongodb or something else for big online sales site

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cassandra, mongoose, cassandra-2.0

Currently we are using mongodb as our primary store for big online sales site, and currently we are focusing ourselves on big scalability among multiple machines.

Site backend is written in node.js and we are using mongoose as ODM.

I can see many blog posts which are writing about awesome cassandra DB, and I am starting to think about switching to cassandra. But still I am not sure if this is a really good decision, because I didn't found any good ODM/ORM lib for cassandra and node.js (and writing raw queries can be pain. Also writing good tested ORM/ODM can be time consuming task). So I am not sure how much benefit will I have after this switch. We are using elasticsearch as search engine, and it works excellent in combination with mongodb, and I am asking my self will do also good with cassandra.

If you have any experiance with this, it will be very helpfull.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you experience any performance problems or other problems whatsoever? And what exactly is big?

Comment: We don't have any problems for now. Big is around 100GB of data.

Comment: Reading up the Cassandra industry use cases at http://planetcassandra.org/industry-use-cases/ may help. Ctrl + F for "eCommerce" on that page, which I suppose is most relevant to your use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cassandra is a very nicely designed database, which can fulfill a lot of scenarios. MongoDB is also a really good DB engine. So let me just compare couple of main bullet points for you.

***Always on* system**

Cassandra is really great when you need to provide 24x7 operations in multiple data centers. If you got more then one datacenter with multiple servers in each of them then Cassandra is great for you. Cassandra can sync writes to more than one datacenter and maintain desired data consistency across complex set ups. Recovery and re-sync is also quite easy.

On the other note MongoDB is easy to operate. If you got one data center and only couple of servers it might be a perfect fit (although global write lock might be a pain over time). In simple deployments it's easy to maintain and monitor.

**Scalability**

To continue the above statements - Cassandra is linearly scalable. There is, literally, no limit of how big the cluster will be. Your writes will always stay fast, while reads might become more complicated over time - depending on the structure of your data.

**Denormalization of data**

With Cassandra your writes and reads can be extremely fast if you will create a structure that will reflect what you need to get from your data. There is no query language (well, there is, but it's not exactly SQL) that you can use to *reorganize* your result set using aggregates, groupings, etc. Yes, some things are doable and some not - that is very specific to Cassandra data model. You will have to implement a lot of things on your own and write the result to the DB - i.e. counters for aggregation, different groupings, etc.

In comparison MongoDB is easy to use, easier to learn and more flexible - both for development (as knowledge curve/efforts goes) and for implementation of business logic (as time/effort is considered). That is - kind of - a reason why there are ORM engines for MongoDB and only couple (very limited) for Cassandra.

---

To summarize - both DBs are really good... if you will embrace their limitations. If you got **only** 100GB of data and you need flexible, easy to implement DB engine I would stick to MongoDB, alternatively take a look [RethinkDB](http://rethinkdb.com) which have a very similar model and way better (in my personal opinion) clustering/data center replication implementation.

Cassandra is a great option for you if you will need to store TBs of data soon, deploying your apps across multiple data centers while accepting the cost of additional efforts to implement the same features and maintaining similar capabilities.

Don't take it personally that I have used the word *only* while describing your data set. Yes, it's not big - my company stores more than 20 TB these days... so yeah, 100GB is really not that much...

---

To stop everyone from pointing that I should compare some other features or point out some other differences between those two - it's just a rough, high level overview on the things I consider relevant to the problem, not a full comparison or analysis of the problem. But feel free to point out what I have missed and I will be happy to include new stuff in this answer...

Comment: Thank you on your answer. I had the same opinion. You just confirmed it.